# Include levels of zero count in result of table()

Tags: r, count, missing-data

I have a vector 'y' and I count the different values using `table`:

```
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 4)
table(y)
# y
# 0 1 3 4 
# 2 1 1 2
```

However, I also want the result to include the fact that there are zero 2's and zero 5's. Can I use `table()` for this?

Desired result:

```
# y
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 1 0 1 2 0
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Convert your variable to a `factor`, and set the categories you wish to include in the result using `levels`. Values with a count of zero will then also appear in the result:

```
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 4)
table(factor(y, levels = 0:5))
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 1 0 1 2 0
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer.
What if the levels are string factors?

Comment: @SteveMcManaman The same thing: `y <- c("A","A","B","D","E","E");` `table(factor(y,levels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F")))` will produce a similar result