# Tables in R/Rstudio- how to include all response options in a table

Tags: r, tabulate

I am running some demographic data in R.  I have created new variables which show what responses represent what demographic.  Here is the example of the code I am running

```
data$race <- NULL
data$race [data$q1 == 1] <- "White"
data$race [data$q1 == 2] <- "Black / African American"
data$race [data$q1 == 3] <- "Hispanic / Latino"
data$race [data$q1 == 4] <- "Asian"
...
```

The problem I am encountering is that not every demographic appears in my data set.  As such, when I run the table, some demographics don't show up.

```
    table (data$race)

White     Black / African American     Hispanic / Latino
100       100                          25
```

I want to create a table that lists the empty demographics as zero.

```
    table (data$race)

White     Black / African American     Hispanic / Latino     Asian
100       100                          25                    0
```

I am not sure if there is an option in table to do this.  Does anyone know of a way to code this?  I tried exclude = FALSE, but that just creates an  column.  Is there a different option I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include levels of zero count in result of table()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617061/include-levels-of-zero-count-in-result-of-table) Looks like you can set the _levels_ argument in the function to capture groups that have 0 records. `table(data$race, levels = c("White", "Black / African American", "Hispanic / Latino", "Asian"))`

Comment: Alternatively you can make `race` a factor with `data$race <- factor(data$q1, labels = c("White", "Black / African American", "Hispanic / Latino", "Asian"))`.

Comment: The factor method works very well.  I also use as.data.frame () to make the table easier to read.  Thanks for your help.