# Include levels of zero count in result of wpct() (weighted table of percentages) in R

Tags: r, count, frequency, missing-data, weighted

I have a problem similar to this one: [Include levels of zero count in result of table()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617061/include-levels-of-zero-count-in-result-of-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) Yet, I'm not using `table()` but `wpct()` from the ['weights'](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjTh4KcvtnyAhUa_6QKHTcECBcQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fweights%2Fweights.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1BqaAc-qmA92j8OyE6uV9w) package. Sadly, the solution provided for `table()` does not work with `wpct()`:

```
test <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5)
weight <- c(.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)

wpct(test, weight)
#        1         2         3         5 
#0.2121212 0.1818182 0.3636364 0.2424242

wpct(factor(test, levels = 0:5), weight)
#        1         2         3         5 
#0.2121212 0.1818182 0.3636364 0.2424242
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `complete` to create a missing observation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(weights)
tibble(test, weight) %>% 
   complete(test = 1:5, fill = list(weight = 0)) %>% 
   summarise(out = wpct(test, weight))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
    out
  <dbl>
1 0.212
2 0.182
3 0.364
4 0    
5 0.242
```

Comment: Thanks Arun Kirshna! :-) May I ask you a follow-up? If I use your code, it works perfectly fine. If I then replace 'test' and 'weight' with the actual variable names, I get an error message: Error: unexpected '=' in "  complete(data.engl$Q03_3 =" Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @TiF it should be `data.engl$` instead it would be just `Q03_3`

Comment: i.e. `complete(Q03_3, ...`

Comment: super!! With attach(data.engl) before and detach(data.engl) after the code, it works nicely! Thanks!!

Comment: @TiF if it is a data.frame, you don't need attach i.e. `complete(data.engl, Q03_3, ...) or `data.engl %>% complete(Q03_3, ..`