Accuracy from Confusion Matrix when Number of Rows May Change in R
I am generating confusion matrices that will usually be 2x2 (predicted and actual values of 0 AND 1), but will sometimes be 1x2 (actual of 0 AND 1, but predicted will only be 0 OR 1).  I am using the table function as:
CONF_MATRIX <- table(predicted_values, actual_values)
I want to manually calculate the accuracy for each matrix ((TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN)). I'm guessing something like the following would work:
Accuracy <- (CONF_MATRIX["0", "0"] + CONF_MATRIX["1", "1"]) / sum(CONF_MATRIX))
but has to include a check to see if CONF_MATRIX["0", "0"] and CONF_MATRIX["1", "1"] exist in the first place. Please suggest code that can calculate accuracy for the two possible cases.

The way to do this would be to make each of the inputs a factor, like table(factor(predicted_values, levels=c(0,1)), factor(actual_values, levels=c(0,1))) so that the table is always 2x2 regardless of whether the values are present.

Essentially an extension of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617061/include-levels-of-zero-count-in-result-of-table/1617150

The numerator can be calculated as:
for (j in 1:nrow(CONF_MATRIX))
    {SUM_CORRECT <- SUM_CORRECT + CONF_MATRIX[rownames(CONF_MATRIX)[j], rownames(CONF_MATRIX)[j]]
    }

